# Как лучше совершить поиск по массиву с объектами?

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти в каком элементе массива находится значение например "цветы", при этом нужно что бы когда я искал допустим по запросу "цвет" он выдавал все возможные варианты, как это лучше сделать?

```
 [
      {
        name: 'Важные',
        location: [
          'Продукты',
          'Цветы',
        ]
      },
    {
        name: 'Важные2',
        location: [
          'Продукты2',
          'Цветы2',
        ]
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
      {
        name: 'Важные',
        location: [
          'Продукты',
          'Цветы',
        ]
      },
    {
        name: 'Важные2',
        location: [
          'Продукты2',
          'Цветы2',
        ]
}];

let search = 'Цветы';
let result = arr.filter(el => el.location.find(location => location.indexOf(search) !== -1));
console.log(result);
console.log('---------------------------');
search = 'Цветы2';
result = arr.filter(el => el.location.find(location => location.indexOf(search) !== -1));
console.log(result);

console.log('---------------------------');
console.log('---------------------------');
let filterArrByLocation = (arr, searchString) => {
    return arr.filter(el => el.location.find(location => location.indexOf(searchString) !== -1));
}

console.log(filterArrByLocation(arr, 'Цветы2'));
```